# Defualt Activity Not found in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest

My App was working good and correctly suddenly android show me this Error before Building
My Manifest is Correct and i done evrythink that shuold be done like Invalid And restart Catch
Deleting android studio setting and config files and etc and this is my manifest file below there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.smartHouseApp"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.zxing.client.android" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application
    android:name=".App.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="pushe_token"
        android:value="wk2xorljq07w6g034wwm1w6lmo5g9mypn3814vz5" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.RemoteInfoActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.Others.KeysActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.Others.ConfigKeysActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.Others.OthersActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.NewRemoteInfo"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.IrDevicesActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.DeviceProtocol"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Settings.SecurityActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Settings.NotificationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.HouseSettingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ForgetPasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".Activities.UserRegister.StagTwoActivity$SmsListener"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.UserRegister.StageThreeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.UserRegister.StagTwoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.UserRegister.StageOneActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.DeviceUpdateActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.DeviceType"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.DeviceBrand"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.DeviceModels"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SampleActivity.Main2Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Log.SearchActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.IntroduceActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.LogInfoActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.Log.LogActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.AboutUsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Room.WifiConfigureActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ShowUserActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.MyQrScannerActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MyBirthdayPicker"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.SpecificActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Devices.MainPage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.MainPage" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Room.AddDeviceToScenario"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Room.SpecificDeviceActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Room.NewRoomActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.VoiceInfoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.VoiceCommandActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.EditUsersSubActivtiy.SubUsersActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.EditUsersSubActivtiy.ChangePasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.EditUsersSubActivtiy.EditUserInfoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MyTimePicker"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.DeviceRegisterActivities.RegisterViaViewPager"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ShowingRoomsAndDevicesActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.AddNewDeviceToRoom"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.AddingDeviceToScenarioActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.DeviceActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.ScenarioInfoActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.MyScenarioActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.VoiceRecorderActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MyScenarioCreateActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Room.MyHomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.AddDeviceActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ConnectionDown"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ServerDownActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.InBuildActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MessagesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.SettingMenuActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.RequestActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ProfileActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.AccessPointActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.sms_registeryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.LoadingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.FingerLogInActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Room.AddDeviceToRoomActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
    </provider>

    <service android:name=".MyService.MyService" />
    <service android:name=".MyService.MyAdvancedService" />
    <service android:name=".MyService.CheckingService" />

    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
</application>
```

hope to some one help me

Comment: Just somthing to say : my manifest has been ended at the end  of manifest but its dosent taken in the upper text

Answer (score 0):

In one of your activities in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file you need to add something like the following:

```
<activity            
  android:label="Main Activity"
  android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter >
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You need an `intent-filter` for `Main` and `Launcher`.

```
<intent-filter >
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your "main activity" at bottom of app declaration like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.smartHouseApp"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.zxing.client.android" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application
    android:name=".App.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
   <activity
        android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="pushe_token"
        android:value="wk2xorljq07w6g034wwm1w6lmo5g9mypn3814vz5" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.RemoteInfoActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.Others.KeysActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.Others.ConfigKeysActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.Others.OthersActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.NewRemoteInfo"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.IrDevicesActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.DeviceProtocol"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Settings.SecurityActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Settings.NotificationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.HouseSettingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ForgetPasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".Activities.UserRegister.StagTwoActivity$SmsListener"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.UserRegister.StageThreeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.UserRegister.StagTwoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.UserRegister.StageOneActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.DeviceUpdateActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.DeviceType"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.DeviceBrand"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.DeviceModels"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SampleActivity.Main2Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Log.SearchActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.IntroduceActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.LogInfoActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.Log.LogActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.AboutUsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Room.WifiConfigureActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ShowUserActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.MyQrScannerActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MyBirthdayPicker"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.SpecificActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Devices.MainPage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.IrContoller.MainPage" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Room.AddDeviceToScenario"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Room.SpecificDeviceActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Room.NewRoomActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.VoiceInfoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.VoiceCommandActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.EditUsersSubActivtiy.SubUsersActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.EditUsersSubActivtiy.ChangePasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.EditUsersSubActivtiy.EditUserInfoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MyTimePicker"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.DeviceRegisterActivities.RegisterViaViewPager"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ShowingRoomsAndDevicesActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.AddNewDeviceToRoom"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.AddingDeviceToScenarioActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.DeviceActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.ScenarioInfoActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.MyScenarioActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.VoiceRecorderActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MyScenarioCreateActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Room.MyHomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.AddDeviceActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ConnectionDown"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ServerDownActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.InBuildActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MessagesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.SettingMenuActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.RequestActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ProfileActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.AccessPointActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.sms_registeryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.LoadingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.FingerLogInActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Room.AddDeviceToRoomActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
    </provider>

    <service android:name=".MyService.MyService" />
    <service android:name=".MyService.MyAdvancedService" />
    <service android:name=".MyService.CheckingService" />

    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
</application>
```

If it doesn't work, are you sure of your package name.
Try to set others activity:

```
android.intent.category.DEFAULT
```